# UdpClient does not receive any data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, udpclient

So, This has me confused for a while. I can't think of a simpler program to write and test. I initialize the `UdpClient` and call `Receive` method on a separate thread.Here is the complete code:

```
UdpClient client = new UdpClient(1414);            
        byte[] data = new byte[320];
        IPEndPoint localpt = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,0);
        const string START_COMMAND = "START";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            client.Connect("192.168.1.12",33051);

            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                while (client.Available > 0)
                {
                    data=client.Receive(ref localpt);
                }                    
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] START_BYTES = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(START_COMMAND);
            client.Send(START_BYTES, START_BYTES.Length);
        }
```

After setting a breakpoint on `while (client.Available > 0)` I noticed that client.Available is always zero.
Things that I've tried:
1-Check if I'm able to ping the remote host(OK I am able to Ping)
2-Check if there is any data available on the network interface(OK Used wireshark and saw incoming packets)
3-Check if my application is allowed to go through firewall(OK Explicitly added my exe to go through windows firewall)
4-Disable(Uninstall) any firewall or antivirus programs(OK)
Yet I cannot receive any data from inside my app. Through further investigation I found out that it is possible to send data(The remote host receives my data) but I can never receive any.

Comment: UDP send and receive uses the same sockets.  So use : byte[] data = sender_socket.Receive(ref localpt);

Comment: @jdweng why? Is it problematic to use the same socket for sending and receiving?

Comment: Absolutely NO!!! You can only have one socket with the same three parameters 1) Source IP address 2) End IP address 3) Port Number.  You will receive an exception if you try to have both Send and Receive Socket with same parameters.

Comment: @jdweng for clarification, deleted sender socket from code which is not used. is this code correct now?

Comment: See msdn examples.  The examples uses socket and can be replaced with any class that inherits the socket like UdpClient.